# In MongoDB, is it safe to copy the DOB and GENDER column to all tables?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

So my APP has a table to host the `User`. Each user has a `DOB` and `GENDER`.

Of course, these fields will never change.

In other tables where I need this information from the `User`, such as:

```
const image_schema = () => {
  const common_fields = {
    user_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    file_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  };
  return new mongoose.Schema(common_fields, {
    collection: `Image`,
    timestamps: true,
  });
};
```

Is it better to copy these 2 columns, breaking normalization, or is it better to look them up from the `User`'s reference?

This lookup is not a join, hence it should scale?

Comment: The choice depends on your actual scenario like how frequently you need to reference the 2 fields in your use case. You may want to check out [this article related to denormalization](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3) about the rules for making the choice.

Comment: "these fields will never change" is a bit naive statement unless you plan to keep the db on a cold wallet. People make typos, sometimes they don't realise the mistake until it's in the db. At this point the "never" ends.